# Run JSHint in C# runtime

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, jshint

I have a .net c# program that uses JavaScript .NET as an internal scripting language.

What I would like to do is to be able to validate the JavaScript from within the c# runtime and have the program return any errors that JSHint finds.  Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is. Call the service using `HttpWebRequest` and then parse the HTTP response to be able to display it.